# where is the correct man directory for my latexdiff files?

Tags: latexdiff, mac, directory

Mac user here. I am trying to execute the following in the terminal:

latexdiff draft.tex revision.tex > diff.tex

But it is returning this:

Input file draft.tex does not exist. at /usr/texbin/latexdiff line 516,  line 20681.

I can't figure out which is the correct man directory in which to copy the draft.tex and revision.tex files.

Please help/

Comment: It took me a while after reading *Where is the correct man?*

Comment: the term "man directory" came from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff directions item 2: "2. Copy latexdiff.1 and latexrevise.1 into the correct man directory" --- i simply did not know what correct man directory meant. I now realize it meant wherever my current directory is, else I need to change directory of the terminal to where my files are.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to running the program from a wrong directory

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i figured it out. It's somewhat embarrassing. I first needed to change the directory by doing typing "cd /Users/mac/Desktop" because my files to be latexdiff'ed are on my desktop.